In ubuntu 24.04LTS, the part equivalent to MS Windows Explorer and characters are not displayed when viewing files
I am currently using ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and since the beginning of the installation, I have been having problems with text not being displayed in the file explorer (?) and other areas. When I move the mouse cursor, it seems to only display where I moved it, but after a while it disappears again. Is there anything I can do about this problem?

I translated from Japanese. ここでは英語を使用してください。ありがとうございます!
